# Django Not Serving Staticfiles after collectstatic

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

So I'm following this tutorial on serving staticfiles after collectstatic and after changing from {% load static %} to {% load staticfiles %}

AND adding

```
`
+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` to urls.py

AND adding
    `

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]`
```

to the url pattern it still is not loading the static files. I tried using findstatic and it still tries to look in static instead of staticfiles. I would appreciate any help, I've tried reading the documentation and added everything but it refuses to look at staticfiles folder and goes to static.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-django-templates-static-files#toc-settings-for-managing-static-files

https://github.com/amos-o/djangotemplates

Comment: You should just keep `{% load static %}` and just add `STATIC_ROOT` to your `settings.py`, run `python manage.py collectstatic` and it will work with `python manage.py runserver`. Make sure that files are actually copied to `STATIC_ROOT` folder.

Comment: The paragraph about changing to `load staticfiles` because of migration of files to the `STATIC_ROOT` (which is `staticfiles` in that example) is totally wrong.

Comment: django does not serve static files from static root. nginx must serve static files instead of django